# how to get the indices with a specific text from List?

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have a List

```cs
 List<String> myArray = new List<string>()
        {
            "sometext",    /*1*/
            "desireText",  /*2*/
            "sometext",    /*3*/
            "sometext",    /*4*/
            "desireText",  /*5*/
            "desireText",  /*6*/
            "sometext",    /*7*/
            "sometext",    /*8*/
            "desireText",  /*9*/
            "sometext",    /*10*/
            "desireText",  /*11*/
            "desireText",  /*12*/
            "desireText",  /*13*/
            "sometext",    /*14*/
            "sometext",    /*15*/
            "sometext"     /*16*/
        };
```

I wrote wrong code:

```cs
List<Int32> indexes = new List<Int32>();
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Count; i++)
        {
            if (IsValidText(myArray[i]))
            {
                indexes.Add(i-1);
            }
        }
```

How do I get indices of "desireText" with the condition:
If subsequent elements are equal, then taken only the first index entry.
Ie, the result should be:

```cs
indexes = {1,4,8,10}
```

Comment: What's wrong about that code?

Comment: Maximum consecutive "desiredText" = 5. Between one "desiredText" and other "desiredText" in any case, there will be one or more "sometext".

Comment: @streamdown: result `indexes = {1,4,8,10}` how you expect it? Can you post the code for `IsValidText(string)` as well?

Comment: @SamIam It prints 5, 7, 11, and 12 when it shouldn't.

Comment: You also want to check that the previous item wasn't "desireText"

Comment: Your input _and_ expected results both seem to be using 0-based indices.  The `i-1` seems to be incorrect.

Comment: yes, I was a little mistake when writing the index in the array. Sorry for that)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add the condition to your loop:

```
List<Int32> indexes = new List<Int32>();
bool wasValid = false;  // flag if previous item was valid
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Count; i++)
    {
        if (IsValidText(myArray[i]))
        {
            if (!wasValid) // previous item was not valid
                indexes.Add(i);  // note fix to keep as 0-based index 
            wasValid = true;
        }   
        else
        {
            wasValid = false;  // for next loop
        }
    }
```

You could also probably come up with a Linq method, but it would probably be harder to read and debug and wouldn't be any faster.

Comment: yeah i think that's what he's after.  You'll need to flip `wasValid` to true after you do `indexes.Add()` though.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Only a small addition 
indexes.Add (i-1);

Comment: With the input you provided that would give you `{0,3,7,9}` unless your input was a 1-based index and not a `List<string>`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean `i+1`.  I can't imagine you want a negative-one-based index.

Comment: The expected output given would be right if both arrays are 0-based.  If the input is 1-based and the output is 0-based then `i-1` would be right.